# Vaadin Whitelabel Error Page "Failed to install Node"

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, maven, vaadin, white-labelling

I am using the Vaadin sping boot web app starter and everytime I run the application java file to start the web page, I always get

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to install Node"
```

Followed by hundreds of lines of error messages all related to either node or zip END header not found.
Even though I have Node.js installed on my Laptop.
I'm using JDK 18, Windows 10, IntelliJ community edition 2022.1.2 and Vaadin 22.
Any help on how to get my localhost up and running would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you see "zip end header not found", you have broken files around. Check the trace if it gives any insight, what files that might be. Most likely not related, but Vaadin v23 is the LTS version - so no point in using 22 anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not mention any build automation tool that you use, you can solve the problem by installing two missing tools (**Node.js** and **npm**) manually.

1. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/download
2. Choose and download installer
3. Make sure npm is also installed (select the option)

Comment: I already had node installed, just was missing npm.